# How to put images on owncloud?

Tags: python-2.7, owncloud

I want to put some Images on my owncloud by python.

here is some code that can put txt,but I have no idea how to put my images(png) on owncloud.

```
import owncloud
oc = owncloud.Client('http://domain.tld/owncloud')
oc.login('user', 'password')
oc.mkdir('testdir')
oc.put_file('testdir/remotefile.txt', 'localfile.txt')
link_info = oc.share_file_with_link('testdir/remotefile.txt')
print "Here is your link: " + link_info.get_link()
```

Thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
def test():
    import owncloud

    oc = owncloud.Client('http://1.1.6.115')

    oc.login('aaa', 'aaa')
    try:
        oc.mkdir('test')
    except:
        print 'do not create fold'
    oc.put_file('test/test.png',u"K:/123/test.png")

    link_info = oc.share_file_with_link('test/test.png')
```

I get it .